# Computing spatial force applied by the end-effector on the environment

Tags: drake

If I have a robot with generalized positions, velocities and accelerations as q, q_dot and q_ddot, I would like to compute the force that the end-effector applies on the environment in the current configuration.

In theory, the solution for this question would be the equation:

tau = (J_t)*F,

Where tau is the vector of generalized forces applied at the joints, J is the robot Jacobian (J_t the transpose), and F is the spatial force applied on the environment by the end-effector due to the motion of the robot.

How do I calculate the robot Jacobian matrix J using Drake?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [`CalcJacobianSpatialVelocity`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a5f39a8f68fae3de53767a281503a3313) methods of `MultibodyPlant`.  You can find some prose around this [in my course notes](https://manipulation.csail.mit.edu/pick.html#jacobian). We also provide `CalcJacobianTranslationalVelocity`, `CalcJacobianAngularVelocity`.

During a simulation, you may also wish to use MultibodyPlant's [contact_results](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#aa6f63e059613961ba0abb2c1c4532e7c) output port to extract the forces directly.